# CF time and NSDate difference

Tags: ios

1. What are the advantages of one over the other?
2. Can I store CF time as a value in NSDictionary? I know with NSDate you can, but I'm not sure about the other.

Comment: What is `CF time`?

Comment: CFGetAbsoluteTime? Core foundation has a lot of overlapping methods, does it not?

Comment: If you don't know what `CF time` is supposed to mean, how can anyone answer your question? You really need to clarify what you are asking about.